# Optical Flow: Method to estimate a very small displacement

Tags: image-processing, optical-flow

As I was searching for available resources( [here](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/rg/papers/DeepFlow_iccv2013.pdf), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05151), [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5551149/) and many more), I realize that many developed optical algorithm is to estimates **LARGE** displacement. However, there is very limited information or [journals](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0888327016304770) that put effort on estimate very small displacement. The small displacement I'm taking here is at sub-pixel level. The smaller the resolution the better.

So my question, you guys have any idea in mind that might inspire a new method, or suggest an existed method (that I might not be aware of/that can be improved)? Any method/suggestion/comment is very welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confronted to the same problem and I can recommend to use particle filtering. The idea is that instead of using a discretization of the space (which would favor only a limited range of motion detection), the optic flow is computed as a probability density function which is represented by a limited number of samples. These samples (or particles) are precise up to the precision of your computer and can thus detect very small displacments.

Some resources:

- the original paper that led to this idea of applying the particle filter method to computer vision: [http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~misard/condensation.html](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Emisard/condensation.html)
- a first implementation with details on the method: https://laurentperrinet.github.io/publication/perrinet-12-pred/
- a recent implementation : https://github.com/laurentperrinet/Khoei_2017_PLoSCB

Comment: This is a very helpful and informative answer! I don't even know the existence of this kind of filter! Thank you so so much! Now I can progress from there. I see you're the author of the marvelous work above, I would like to take this chance to congratulate you on the amazing work! Is it okay if I refer back to you here in case I encounters problems after going deep into your work?

Comment: thanks for the feedback - all the code is available on the git repo - do not hesitate to contact me directly

Comment: Hi meduz, I got a problem while interpreting your code. Hope you could help me out! In your code line [1020](https://github.com/laurentperrinet/Khoei_2017_PLoSCB/blob/master/scripts/MotionParticlesFLE.py#L1020), is that the intensity of the image at location **x_px** and **y_px**? Since it's an **integer**, wouldn't the likelihood will be very likely the same for all the generated particles? And is the **x** and **y** defined in your code is the pixel location on the images, respective to x-axis and y-axis, or it's pixel displacement?Thanks!

Comment: you are right, the likelihood is computed on the data that is available, that is, on the pixel values from the input movie (but you could think about other input representations...). Still your belief (pdf on motion) can be sub-pixel because it is represented by the particles. Do not hesitate to create an issue using github's tracker if something appears unclear.